# git status shows folders - no extension

Tags: git

When I do a *$ git status*, git shows me folders (besides files). It looks similar to this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    example.folder1/
    example.folder2.subfolder1/
    folder3/bar.c
    folder3/bar.h
    foo.c
    foo.h
```

Currently there are no tracked files in (they contain ignored file though):

```
    example.folder1/
    example.folder2.subfolder1/
```

so I could just add those directories to *.gitignore* but I still want to track these directories in case someone adds tracked files (e.g. *.c *.h) to these folders.

How can I ignore these folders if they contain no files that are tracked? And why do these folders show up anyway? It only happens to some folders, not all.

Comment: Did you check that they contain no hidden files? I don't know any possible reason for such behaviour other than containing untracked files.

Comment: Are you sure you're ignoring the files in sub-folders correctly? For example, `/*.foo` ignores `/abc.foo` but not `/example.folder1/abc.foo`. See [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) for more info.

Comment: @Frax No hidden files!

Comment: @mkasberg I have not thought about that, that may be a reason why I got so many folders that show up. I'll read through the manual.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folders contain untracked files that are not ignored. If you want to remove the folders from the "untracked" list, you can either:

- add the folder to the gitignore,
- or add all of the files in the folder to the gitignore.

In other words, the folder will continue to show up as untracked as long as there are one or more untracked files in it which are not ignored.

Comment: You were right. There was a file type that I did not add to .gitignore. Follow up question: shouldn't git status show me those files individually and not only the directory?

Comment: If all the files in a directory (which are not ignored) are untracked, git will just show the directory as untracked. I'm not sure off the top of my head if there's an option to change this. But you can `cd` into the directory and run git status again.

Comment: That is interesting then. I ignored some file types within *example.folder1/* but left a file type out (one .xml file was in that particular folder: *merkur.xml*). Git would still display the directory */../example.folder1/* and **not** */../example.folder1/merkur.xml*. My assumption is, that I did something weird in my *.gitignore* or I made a mistake during the *git add*.